# Language on my custom module

Tags: extensions, language

I'm developing a module and i want to set up a multiple language support to my custom module.

So my procedure are this on my custom module root directory is something like this.

```
mod_module
-admin
--language
---en-GB
-----en-GB.mod_module.ini
```

inside on my **en-GB.mod_module.ini**

```
MOD_MODULE_DESCRIPTION = "Sample Description for my module"
```

now on my manifest xml file.

```
 <description>MOD_MODULE_DESCRIPTION</description>  
  </administration>
        <languages folder="admin/language">
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_module.ini</language>         
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_module.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>
    </administration>
```

eventhough I follow the correct instructions in joomla docs,
upon installation the **MOD_MODULE_DESCRIPTION** is not working.
I know that once you successfully installed your extension joomla show a feedback message with the description of your extension.

why its not working?

Answer (score 1):

Well ok, that was a hassle. Basically put your language files in

```
-language
--eng-GB
---eng-GB.mod_module.ini
---eng-GB.mod_module.sys.ini
```

and then put this in your xml file, but not inside the administration block.

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_module.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_module.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

For some reason joomla! is really picky about this on loading this on the installation phase, even thou everything might work afterwards.

Oh and credit where credit is due. Here I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186611/load-language-file-during-joomla-2-5-system-plugin-installation).